# Ханойская башня на C++. Итеративный метод

Tags: c++

Я изучаю язык С++ по книге, дошла до рекурсии в C++. После главы было задание "Ханойская башня". Проблема заключается в следующем: как решить данную задачу методом рекурсии, я поняла сама, но в книге было предложено решить ту же задачу итеративным методом, и вот с этим возникли проблемы. В целом я поняла, как нужно перекладывать диски в зависимости от четности или нечетности их количества: если четное, то первый диск перекладывается на промежуточный колышек, иначе - на финишный. В процессе решения я пыталась перекладывать, начиная с 1 диска, постепенно увеличивая количество переложенных дисков, так, если нужно переложить 5 дисков с 1-ого на 3-ий колышек, то 1 диск я клала на 3, далее нужно переложить следующий диск из начальной стопки на 2-ой колышек и на него 1 диск, 2 диска переложено, затем кладем 3-ий диск на 3-ий колышек, на него нужно положить те 2 диска, чтобы их переложить, нужно также начинать с одного, и я никак не могла продумать эту идею, никак не выходило в цикле отслеживать сколько мне еще переложить и при этом менять статус колышков(стартовый, промежуточный, финишный). Пыталась найти решение и натыкалась на способы с использованием векторов и массивов, этого в моей книге еще не было, следовательно, мне нужно решить это как-то иначе.

Comment: Данным способом предлагается решить, чтобы лучше усвоить материал главы, а не перепрыгивать на то, что будет в следующей.

Comment: "Попытайтесь написать итеративную версию задачи о Ханойских башнях. Если вам это удастся, сравните вашу итеративную версию с рекурсивной, разработанной в предыдущем упражнении. Исследуйте вопросы производительности, ясности и возможности обосновать корректность программ." - так звучит задание из книги. Я просто не хочу это оставлять, уже достаточно долго сижу, не дает покоя эта задача, интересно, как все же можно ее решить.

Comment: Разжеванного ответа никто не просил. Я просила разъяснить место моего ступора. Спасибо за ответы.

Comment: Вы говорите, что находили решения с использованием массивов и что у вас в книге этого еще не было. Но ведь сама башня в программе наверняка в виде 3х массивов лежит. Я по крайней мере другого способа хранения башни не вижу.

Comment: Когда решала эту задачу рекурсивно, то я нигде башню не хранила, она существует просто условно. У меня там была функция, принимающая 4 параметра: количество дисков, стартовый, промежуточный и финишный колышки, указывались просто их номера. И происходила смена статуса колышков, т.е. при следующем вызове этой функции, например финишный и промежуточный колышки менялись.

Comment: Хм. А как же вы работоспособность кода проверяли для разных начальных состояний башни. Как эти самые состояния задавали. Вас там в книге imho чему то странному учат ...

Comment: Книга "Как программировать на C++." Х.М. Дейтел, П.Дж. Дейтел.

Comment: @SJerin не слушайте никого, кроме себя. Если задачу можно решить лучшим способом — решайте сразу. Вас учат `конформизму`, а нужно быть непосредственным. По обложке сразу видно, что книга не робкого десятка, а так, ради быстрых `$`.

Comment: есть отличная статья на хабре [ханойская башня на пальцах](http://habrahabr.ru/post/200758/)

Answer (score 1):

Вот Вам в помощь отрывок из книги ***А. Шень. Программирование: теоремы и задачи 2-е изд., М.: МЦНМО, 2004, 296 с. ([pdf, 2.1M](http://www.mccme.ru/free-books/shen/shen-progbook.pdf))***:

**8.2.1.**  Написать нерекурсивную программу для нахождения последовательности перемещений колец в задаче о ханойских башнях.

**Решение.**

Вспомним  рекурсивную  программу,  перекладывающую
`i` верхних колец с `m` на `n`:

```pascal
procedure move(i,m,n: integer);
  var s: integer;
begin
  if i = 1 then begin
    writeln (’сделать ход ’, m, ’->’, n);
  end else begin
    s:=6-m-n; {s - третий стержень: сумма номеров равна 6}
    move (i-1, m, s);
    writeln (’сделать ход ’, m, ’->’, n);
    move (i-1, s, n);
  end;
end;
```

Видно, что задача "переложить `i` верхних дисков с `m`-го стержня на `n`-ый" сводится к трём задачам того же типа: двум задачам с `i-1` дисками и к одной задаче с единственным диском. Занимаясь этими задачами, важно не позабыть, что ещё осталось сделать.

Для этой цели заведём *стек отложенных заданий*, элементами которого будут тройки `(i,m,n)`. Каждая такая тройка интерпретируется как заказ "переложить `i` верхних дисков с `m`-го стержня на `n`-ый". Заказы упорядочены в соответствии с требуемым порядком их выполнения: самый срочный - вершина стека. Получаем такую программу:

```pascal
procedure move(i,m,n: integer);
begin
  сделать стек заказов пустым
  положить в стек тройку <i,m,n>
  {инвариант: осталось выполнить заказы в стеке}
  while стек непуст do begin
    удалить верхний элемент, переложив его в <j,p,q>
    if j = 1 then begin
      writeln (’сделать ход’, p, ’->’, q);
    end else begin
      s:=6-p-q;
        {s - третий стержень: сумма номеров равна 6}
      положить в стек тройки <j-1,s,q>, <1,p,q>, <j-1,p,s>
    end;
  end;
end;
```

(Заметим, что первой в стек кладётся тройка, которую надо выполнять
последней.) Стек троек может быть реализован как три отдельных стека. (Кроме того, в паскале есть специальный тип, называемый "запись" (`record`), который может быть применён.)

Comment: Или меня обманывают глаза, или это Паскаль.

Comment: Он самый, ну если дать готовое решение вопрошающему, он (она) ничему не научится, я так понял человек для себя решает задачи из книги, чтобы научиться программировать, а не для кого-то)

Answer (score 1):

Я очень долго бился над этой задачей. Но я написал решение без рекурсии, без стека. С помощью массива и ассоциацией ханойской башни с бинарным деревом.

Когда решал, то пол дня даже подойти к задаче не мог, но ближе к вечеру понял, что ханойская башня очень сильно похоже на бинарное дерево. Тогда я сменил ракурс направления с Башни на Дерево. Так я провёл два дня в поисках наилучшего обхода бинарного дерева без рекурсии. Но в конце получилось как всегда - за мудрёно и не понятно: Я нашёл такие правила при которых я получаю бинарное дерево на уровень выше и описал это в функции  getMove();

Правила просты:

1. проход в левое поддерево
2. подъём с левого поддерева
3. проход в правое поддерево
4. подъём с правого поддерева

Тут надо отметить, что 1 и 2 - это swap(in, tmp), а 3 и 4 - это swap(from, tmp)

Тогда мы получаем, что дерево из 2 уровней будет иметь такое решение 1234, а так как дерево с 3 уровнями два 2-ух уровневых дерева сцепленных узлом, то что бы получить дерево 3 уровня нам надо:

1. Скопировать нынешнее дерево, что бы получить два.
2. Добавить в начало и конец по 1 и 4 соответственно.
3. Добавить в середину 23

Таким образом: 1234 -> 1 1234 23 1234 4;
И если сейчас пройтись по правилам, то мы обойдём бинарное дерево. Что бы же напечатать вывод мы должны учесть, что печать будет производиться только на последнем уровне при 1 и 3 , а так же на любом при 2. Теперь у нас есть всё, что бы решить эту задачу.

Теперь, когда мы можем обойти бинарное дерево, то мы можем написать решение задачи:

getMove - возвращает массив действий;
count - нужен для хранения длины массивы

```
int* getMove(int n, int &count) {
int* mas = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*count);
mas[0] = 1;mas[1] = 2;mas[2] = 3;mas[3] = 4;

for (int i = 1; i <= n - 2; i++) {
    count *= 2;
    count += 4;
    //Изменённый массив
    int *tmp = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * count);
    //Добавляем в начало 1
    tmp[0] = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i <= (count - 4) / 2; i++) {
        tmp[i] = mas[i-1];
    }
    //Добавляем в середину 23
    tmp[count / 2 - 1] = 2;
    tmp[count / 2] = 3;

    for (int i = count / 2 + 1; i < count; i++) {
        tmp[i] = mas[i-(count / 2 + 1)];
    } 
    //Добавляем в конец 4
    tmp[count - 1] = 4;
    
    free(mas);
    mas = tmp;
}

return mas;
}
```

Теперь реализуем функции на каждое действие от 1 до 4

```
void _1(int &level, int &from, int &in, int &tmp) {
swap(in, tmp);
level--;
if (level == 1) print(from, in);
}

void _2(int &level, int &from, int &in, int &tmp) {
swap(in, tmp);
level++;
print(from, in);
}

void _3(int& level, int& from, int& in, int& tmp) {
swap(from, tmp);
level--;
if (level == 1) print(from, in);
}

void _4(int& level, int& from, int& in, int& tmp) {
swap(from, tmp);
level++;
}
```

И вот мы подобрались к функции, которая производит работу:

```
void work(int n, int from, int in, int tmp) {
if (n == 1) {
    print(from, in);
    return;
}

int count = 4;
int* arr = getMove(n, count);

int level = n;

for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    switch (arr[i]) {
    case 1: _1(level, from, in, tmp); break;
    case 2: _2(level, from, in, tmp); break;
    case 3: _3(level, from, in, tmp); break;
    case 4: _4(level, from, in, tmp); break;
    default: 
        break;
    }
}
}
```

Вот main:

```
int main() { 
SetConsoleCP(1251);
SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);

int from = 1;
int in = 3;
int tmp = 2;
int count = 4;

printf("from = %d; in = %d; tmp = %d; count = %d.\n",from, in, tmp, count);
printf("Recursion method.\n");
hanoi(from, in, tmp, count);

printf("------------------\n");

printf("Iterative method.\n");
work(count, from, in, tmp);

system("pause");

return 0;
}
```

Конечно же можно много чего убрать или добавить, но как говориться - "Работает не трогай".

Answer (score 0):

Если кому интересно с++ версия без стека без массива без рекурсии. Чистая итерация и больше ничего.В книге П.Дейтела еще не изучались массивы для написания итеративной версии.
Там надо написать только с помощью итерации.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>   
using namespace std;    
int max(int a)            /*возвращает максимальный показатель степени числа 2*/
{                         /*который показывает уровень надстройки*/
    int p = 1,temp, p1;
    while (pow(2, p) <= a)
    {
        temp = pow(2, p);
        if (a % temp == 0 && temp <= a)
                   p1 = p;
        p++;
    }   
    return p1;
}
 int step(int a)  /*возвращает номер позиции для четных номеров*/
{       
    return a / pow(2,max(a));
}
int count_step_define(int a, bool rev_along)/*возвращает номер колышка с которого будет очередной шаг*/
{       
    if (rev_along)
    {   
        int temp = ((step(a) - 1) / 2) % 3;
        if (max(a) % 2 == 0)
            return 1 + temp;
        else
        {
            if(1 - temp == 0)
                    return 3;
            else
                    return 1 - temp > 0? 1 - temp: 2;
        }
    }        
    else
            return 1 + ((a - 1) / 2) % 3;
}
int main()
    {
    unsigned long long n, loop, a = 1;      
    cin >> n;   /*количество дисков*/
    loop = pow(2, n) - 1;   /*количество требуемых перемещений*/    
    while (a <= loop)
    {   
        int temp, over;
        if (a % 2 == 1)
        {               
              temp = count_step_define(a,0);
             (temp + 1 > 3)? over = 1: over = temp + 1;         
        }
        else
        {                
             temp = count_step_define(a,1);
             if (max(a) % 2 == 0)                
                 (temp + 1 > 3)? over = 1: over = temp + 1;              
             else                
                 (temp - 1 < 1)? over = 3: over = temp - 1;             
        }
        cout << temp << " - >" << over << endl;/*с какого и на какой колышек переместить*/
        a++;            
    }       
     system("pause");
    return 0;
    }
```

Можно  сократить код, но он будет вообще трудно понимаемый. Всем терпения...

Comment: Не стоит использовать `pow` для целочисленного возведения в степень, он может давать неточный ответ. Для степеней двойки лучше `1 << n`.

Answer (score 0):

решил задачу с помощью бинарного дерева, после просмотра этого видео
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2SUvWfNJSsM&ab_channel=3Blue1Brown
Но не смог решить без структур, и массивов.
Вот код

```
    /* hanoi tower itterative */
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <math.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    void hanoi(int, int, int);


    typedef struct
    {
        int index;
        int currentColumnIndex;
    } Disc;

    int main()
    {
        hanoi(3, 3, 1);

        return 0;
    }


    /* itterative hanoi tower solution */
    void hanoi(int discCount, int start, int end)
    {
        Disc *discs;  /* Массив который состоит из дисков */

        if( (discs = (Disc *) malloc(discCount * sizeof(Disc)) ) != NULL){

            int fastPow(int, int);
            int getMovedDiscIndex(int);
            int determinant(int, int, int);

            int counter = 1, movedDiscIndex, column, d;

            /* Порядок выполнения программы завсит от четности числа дисков, начального столба и конечного столба */
            /* Функция determinant возвращает 0 или 1, в зависимости которого меняется порядок выполнения программы */
            d = determinant(discCount, start, end);

            for(counter = 0; counter <= discCount - 1; counter++)
            {
                discs[counter].index = counter;
                discs[counter].currentColumnIndex = start;
            }

            counter = 1;

            /* Алгоритм выполнения */
            while(counter != fastPow(2, discCount))     
            {
                /* Рекурсивные вызовы ханойской башни представлют деревоб которое в свою очередь оченб напоминает комбинации
                вссевозможных двоичных чисел. Количество цифр равно количеству дисков, а индекс перемещаемого диска равен индексу
                первой единицы считая с права. Например если число равен 100101100000, то индекс диска который нужно переместить равен 5,
                поскольку начиная с права, первой единицей является пятая цифра․ Когда число достигает значения 2^n - 1,
                выполнение программы завершается */

                movedDiscIndex = getMovedDiscIndex(counter);   /* Находит индекс диска, который нужно переместить */
                column = discs[movedDiscIndex].currentColumnIndex;

                /* В зависимости от количесива дисков, начальных и конечных полржений, диски могут двигаться по разному */
                /* Если индекс перемещаемого диска четное (не четное в другой конфигурации начальных условий), то диск может
                   двигаться только на следующий стержень, при достижении последнего стержня, счетчик стержня "cбрасывается",
                   таким образом предотвращается возможность перейти на несуществующий стержень*/

                if(movedDiscIndex % 2 == d)
                {
    
                    column = discs[movedDiscIndex].currentColumnIndex;
                    printf("Move disc %d from %d to %d\n", movedDiscIndex + 1, column, column + 1 > 3 ? column - 2 : column + 1);
                    column += 1;
                }
                else 
                {
                    column = discs[movedDiscIndex].currentColumnIndex;
                    printf("Move disc %d from %d to %d\n", movedDiscIndex + 1, column, column + 2 > 3 ? column - 1 : column + 2);
                    column += 2;
                }

                column -= column > 3 ? 3 : 0;
                discs[movedDiscIndex].currentColumnIndex = column;

                ++counter;
            }
        }
        else
            printf("Can't solve hanoi tower. No memory available\n");
    }


    /* Возводит base в степень exponent за Օ(logN) */
    int fastPow(int base, int exponent)
    {
        if(exponent == 0) return 1;

        return exponent % 2 ? base * fastPow(base, exponent - 1) : fastPow(base * base, exponent / 2);
    }

    /* Находит индекс первой единицы, в двоичном числе*/
    int getMovedDiscIndex(int number)
    {
        int movedDiscIndex = 0;

        while(number % 2 != 1)
        {
            number /= 2;
            movedDiscIndex++;
        }

        return movedDiscIndex;
    }


    /* determinant */
    /* В зависимости от конфигурации начальных условий, выбирает вид перемещения - "шагами", либо "прыжками" */
    int determinant(int n, int start, int end)
    {
        if(n % 2 == 0)
        {
            if(start == 1 && end == 2)
                return 1;
            else if(start == 1 && end == 3)
                return 0;
            else if(start == 2 && end == 1)
                return 0;
            else if(start == 2 && end == 3)
                return 1;
            else if(start == 3 && end == 1)
                return 1;
            else
                return 0;
        }else 
        {
            if(start == 1 && end == 2)
                return 0;
            else if(start == 1 && end == 3)
                return 1;
            else if(start == 2 && end == 1)
                return 1;
            else if(start == 2 && end == 3)
                return 0;
            else if(start == 3 && end == 2)
                return 1;
            else
                return 0;
        }
    }
```

Comment: это ответ или новый вопрос?

Comment: Это решение, то есть ответ